# Fetch HTTP request using XML

Tags: javascript, xml, api, xmlhttprequest, fetch-api

I'm trying to make a request to this API which works fine when submitting in the browser with my XML data but I can't see to get it to work with the fetch API. I get STATUS 200 OK but no data. I'm pretty sure I'm not submitting the body correctly but can't work out why?

Checking the console when submitted directly in the browser vs my application I can see the data is submitted with 'params' which I seem to be missing?

Appreciate any guidance.

[my response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HI4L0.png)
[correct response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFrj0.png)

```
const xml =
    '<GetOrderStatus><ClientID>FITE****</ClientID><UserID>FI****</UserID><Password>*****</Password><SecurityKey>*****/SecurityKey><Order><OrderNum>1834006076</OrderNum></Order></GetOrderStatus>';

fetch('http://api.3linx.com/v4/getorderstatus', {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        Accept:
            'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-GB',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
        Connection: 'Keep-alive',
    },
    body: xml,
    
})
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((text) => console.log(text));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, you'll have to use `URLSearchParams` to send your data with `params:`.

```js
const xml =
    '<GetOrderStatus><ClientID>FITE****</ClientID><UserID>FI****</UserID><Password>*****</Password><SecurityKey>*****/SecurityKey><Order><OrderNum>1834006076</OrderNum></Order></GetOrderStatus>';
const form = new URLSearchParams();
form.append('params', xml);
fetch('http://api.3linx.com/v4/getorderstatus', {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        Accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-GB',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
        Connection: 'Keep-alive',
    },
    body: form,
    
})
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((text) => console.log(text));
```

Comment: Thanks. That body definitely looks correct now. Unfortunately, I was still unable to get a response.

Comment: Could you check to see if you have x-www-form-urlencoded enabled on your server? If you are using Express, please take a look at http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.urlencoded

Comment: It's a third party server but when you submit the form on this URL: http://api.3linx.com/v4/getorderstatus I can see the content type in the request is application/x-www-form-urlencoded and I can get XML data back there without any issues....

Comment: Can you check to see if CORS is enabled on that website?

Comment: It seems that you cannot send this fetch over stackoverflow, but you can do so if you paste it into the console (In inspect element) onto http://api.3linx.com/v4/getorderstatus. This most likely means that there is a CORS policy blocking the request.